# SQL Server get the rank without showing the full result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking

Say I have a `Customer` table and a `Purchase` table, with a one to zero or many relationship between `Customer` and `Purchase`.

I understand I can use the `rank()` function in SQL Server to get, for example, the top 10 customers based on the purchase amount. But I would also like to get a specific customer's rank within the entire system, but without returning the entire dataset of customers ranked ahead of that customer.

I'm a little rusty on SQL (Entity Framework's fault, haha) so I wasn't able to build an efficient statement for this query. Does anybody know if `rank()` or some other function can do this?

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit?  You want to get the top 10 customers based on purchase amount, but then what would the other rank value be based on in the whole system? Please show us what you would expect a result set to look like.

Comment: Say you're a user looking at a leaderboard. The leaderboard will show the top 10, but if you're #500 you won't be in this top 10. So the UI would display 11 records...the top 10, and the last one would be #500 with your info on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good candidate for a CTE and using a window function like you mention.  You can declare the specific customer, use a CTE to get all customer's purchase amount, use a second cte to rank them all, then query the top 10 and union the specific customer info. The union will drop the 11th person if they are already in the top 10.  UNION ALL will give you a duplicate record, but provide 11 rows.

```
DECLARE @userID INT = xxxx

;WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT 
customerID
, SUM(purchase_dollars) AS purchase_amount
FROM customer_table

GROUP BY customerID)

, cte_rank AS (
SELECT 
customerID
, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY purchase_amount DESC) AS purchase_amount_rank
--, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY purchase_amount DESC) AS purchase_amount_rank --This will get you 10 records
FROM cte1)

SELECT 
t1.CustomerID
, t2.purchase_amount_rank

FROM customer_table t1
INNER JOIN cte_rank t2
ON t1.customerid = t2.customerid
WHERE t2.purchase_amount_rank <= 10

UNION 

SELECT t1.customerID
, t2.purchase_amount_rank
FROM customer_table t1
INNER JOIN cte_rank t2
ON t1.customerid = t2.customerid
AND t1.customer_id = @userID

ORDER BY t2.purchase_amount_rank
```

Comment: Something worth noting, this can get you potentially thousands of records if they all have the same purchase amounts.  RANK/DENSE_RANK will assign everyone the same rank if they have the same purchase amount.  I will hash in a ROW_NUMBER in the code to accommodate this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an aggregation query:

```
select count(customerid) + 1
from t
where t.value < (select t2.value from t t2 where t2.customerid = @customerid);
```

Note that this specifically does a `rank()`.  Similar (but different) logic is needed for `dense_rank()` and `row_number()`.

This query can make strong use of indexes on `(customerid, value)` and `(value, customerid)`.